# Change a cell's format to boldface if the value is over 500

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel 2010 and trying to add a bunch of rows placing the sum of columns A and B in column C. If the sum is over 500 I would then like to boldface the number in column C. My code below works works mathematically but will not do the bold formatting. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

```
Public Sub addMyRows()
    Dim row As Integer 'creates a variable called 'row'
    row = 2  'sets row to 2 b/c first row is a title
    Do
        Cells(row, 3).Formula = "=A" & row & "+B" & row 'the 3 stands for column C.
            If ActiveCell.Value > 500 Then Selection.Font.Bold = True
        row = row + 1

    'loops until it encounters an empty row
    Loop Until Len(Cells(row, 1)) = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use Conditional Formatting? http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel

Comment: Don't use ActiveCell and Selection! Instead loop over the number of cells in the range, and use MySheet.Cells(i,3).Value > 500 then MySheet.Cells(i,3).Font.Bold=True.

Answer (score 2):

Pure VBA approach:

```
Public Sub AddMyRows()
    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
    LRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range("C2:C" & LRow)
    Rng.Formula = "=A2+B2"
    For Each Cell In Rng
        Cell.Font.Bold = (Cell.Value > 500)
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

An alternative is conditional formatting.

Hope this helps.

Note: The formula in the block has been edited to reflect @simoco's comment regarding a re-run of the code. This makes the code safer for the times when you need to re-run it. :)

Comment: maybe it's better to write: `Cell.Font.Bold = (Cell.Value > 500)` - for the case when values changed and code runs again? It will make all cells with `Cell.Value <= 500` not bold)